# Proof of a Probability Problem by Induction

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, order-statistics

Dear Statisticians and Mathematicians,
I am interested in proving the following lemma by induction
[image]

I have shown that it holds true for $n=2$ which I don't provide its proof here. We assume it is true when $n$ is replaced by $n-1$. I conditioned on $Y_1+...+Y_{n-1}$ but I could not prove. I don't know how to use the induction hypothesis to prove the lemma. I really appreciate any help of you guys in this regard.

Comment: Are you not satisfied with the proof that Ross provides in the text?

Comment: @Math1000 Actually my adviser and I are looking for a simpler proof.